# How do I copy a row from an existing dataframe df_a into a new dataframe df_b?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, iteration

How do I copy a row from an existing dataframe df_a into a new dataframe df_b? Also, a cell from dataframe df_a into the new dataframe df_b? See the following example:

```
for index, row in df__data.iterrows():

     for i in range(df__attributes_to_compare.shape[0]):
        
        if row[df__attributes_to_compare["info_a"].values[i]] != row[df__attributes_to_compare["info_b"].values[i]]:      
             
               # new_df.append(key columns values + unsimiliar compared values)
```

df__data:

| key1 | key2 | key3 | attrb1 | attrb2 | attrb3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sfdg | dagd | dgsg | 12 | 43 | 24 |
| afrtf | yxcbb | ertet | 34 | 45 | 34 |

df__attributes_to_compare:

| info_a | info_b |
| --- | --- |
| attrb1 | attrb2 |
| attrb1 | attrb3 |

new_df, target output:

| key1 | key2 | key3 | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sfdg | dagd | dgsg | 12 | 43 |
| sfdg | dagd | dgsg | 12 | 24 |
| afrtf | yxcbb | ertet | 34 | 45 |

The values that do not match are stored in value1 and value2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following, which is bit more focused:

```py
def select(row):
    col1, col2 = row
    df = df__data[["key1", "key2", "key3"] + [col1, col2]]
    return df[df[col1] != df[col2]].rename(columns={col1: "value1", col2: "value2"})

result = pd.concat(
    map(select, df__attributes_to_compare.itertuples(index=False)),
    axis=0, ignore_index=True
)
```

The `result` is not exactly in the same order given in the question but essentially the same:

```
    key1   key2   key3  value1  value2
0   sfdg   dagd   dgsg      12      43
1  afrtf  yxcbb  ertet      34      45
2   sfdg   dagd   dgsg      12      24
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the suggestion! I also want a version where I avoid itertuples and iterrow. Any ideas?

Comment: @di1a I don't think it makes sense to avoid the use of `itertuples` in this context here. I'd guess that `df__attributes_to_compare` isn't that large?

Comment: In practice, I use instead of `df__data` a dataframe which has millions of rows. According to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues), iterrows should be avoided because the performance is not so good.

Comment: @di1a That should be okay, since the operations on `df__data` are using the vectorized Pandas-methods.

Comment: You mean, since you don't use `itertuples` for `df__data`, it's okay to use it in this case.  And the line `df[df[col1] != df[col2]].rename(columns={col1: "value1", col2: "value2"})` is then the vectorization?

Comment: @di1a Yes, that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"key1":     ["sfdg", "afrtf"],
        "key2":     ["dagd", "yxcbb"],
        "key3":     ["dgsg", "ertet"],
        "attrb1":   ["12", "34"],
        "attrb2":   ["43", "45"],
        "attrb3":   ["24", "34"]}

df__data = pd.DataFrame(data = data)



list_key = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]



# attributes_to_compare = {"info_a": ["attrb1", "attrb1"],
#                          "info_b": ["attrb2", "attrb3"]}

# df__attributes_to_compare = pd.DataFrame(data = attributes_to_compare)



list__attributes_to_compare = ["attrb1", "attrb2", 
                               "attrb1", "attrb3"]



key_set = []
values = []



for index, row in df__data.iterrows():
    
    for i in range(int(len(list__attributes_to_compare)/2)):
        
        i = i*2
        
        if row[list__attributes_to_compare[i]] != row[list__attributes_to_compare[i+1]]:
               
             key_set.append(row.iloc[0:len(list_key)])
             values.append([row[list__attributes_to_compare[i]], row[list__attributes_to_compare[i+1]]])       



df__values = pd.DataFrame(data = values, columns = ["value1", "value2"])

df__key_set = pd.DataFrame(data = key_set, columns = list_key)
df__key_set["new_index"] = np.arange(df__key_set.shape[0])
df__key_set.set_index("new_index", inplace = True)




df__result = df__key_set.merge(df__values, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Does anyone have suggestions for improvement?